# Addition of numbers by comparing it's ID & push it into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I want to add all the numbers having same seq id and push it with summation value into the new array called final as shown below.

INPUT =>

```
$scope.initial = [{seq:11, name:'ABC', number:20},
                  {seq:11, name:'ABC', number:50},
                  {seq:11, name:'ABC', number:80},
                  {seq:12, name:'DEF', number:30},
                  {seq:13, name:'JKL', number:10},
                  {seq:13, name:'JKL', number:15}];
```

OUTPUT =>

```
$scope.final  = [{seq:11, name:'ABC', number:150},
                 {seq:12, name:'DEF', number:30},
                 {seq:13, name:'JKL', number:25}];
```

Thank You!

Comment: Please share your attempt as well.

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks for asking! I have simplified the question, in my code datasets are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $scope.final = [];
 var acc = {};

 for(const {seq, name, number} of $scope.initial){

   if(seq === acc.seq && name === acc.name){
     acc.number += number;
   }else{
     $scope.final.push(acc = {seq, name, number});
   }

 }
```

Just use an accumulator to keep track of the current resulting element. Then check if the currently iterated element matches that accumulator, if so sum up, if not add the current element as the new accumulator.

Comment: Maybe a note that it's using `for of` loop and they may need to use some transpiler like Babel for it to work on browsers properly.

Comment: @Jonas W. it's pushing the correct to the final array but addition is not happening. In 1st loop value is getting pushed without adding

Comment: @JonasW. Thank You! due to some data type mismatch i was not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Loop of the array & check if it has the `seq` if not then add this

```js
var m = [{
    seq: 11,
    name: 'ABC',
    number: 20
  },
  {
    seq: 11,
    name: 'ABC',
    number: 50
  },
  {
    seq: 11,
    name: 'ABC',
    number: 80
  },
  {
    seq: 12,
    name: 'DEF',
    number: 30
  },
  {
    seq: 13,
    name: 'JKL',
    number: 10
  },
  {
    seq: 13,
    name: 'JKL',
    number: 15
  }
];
var grouped = [];
m.forEach(function(a) {
  if (!this[a.seq]) {
    this[a.seq] = {
      seq: a.seq,
      name: a.name,
      number: 0
    };
    grouped.push(this[a.seq]);
  }
  this[a.seq].number = (+this[a.seq].number + +a.number);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to accomplish your task as such:

```
$scope.initial = [
    {seq:11, name:'ABC', number:20},
    {seq:11, name:'ABC', number:50},
    {seq:11, name:'ABC', number:80},
    {seq:12, name:'DEF', number:30},
    {seq:13, name:'JKL', number:10},
    {seq:13, name:'JKL', number:15}
];

var objReduced = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur){
    acc[cur.seq] ? acc[cur.seq].number += cur.number : acc[cur.seq] = cur;
    return acc;
}, {});

$scope.final = Object.keys(objReduced).map(function(x){ return objReduced[x]; });
```